# Using Dense_Rank()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to convey and old SQL script I'm I'm not sure how to use dence fully.
Old code

```
min(T.col1) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY T.col2) as rank
```

Is that the same as

```
Dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY MIN(T.col1) order by T.col2 desc) as Rank
```

Comment: maybe also add oracle tag since it's a question about both?